# 3D DGN Geometrical Data with Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-navisworks

I'm trying to manipulate the data with Forge API coming from AecoSIM 3D models (3D DGN format). All the data is inside the Forge ModelData but the values of geometrical properties are very strange (unit seems to be micrometre for length, i.e. x10e6 ; micrometre2 for area, x10e12 ; micrometre3 for volume, x10e18).

The model has been loaded with following code:

```
var loadOptions = {
  isAEC: true,
  applyScaling: 'm', //always in meter
  applyRefPoint: true
};
await this.viewer!.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, view, loadOptions);
```

[image: Aecosim Properties]

[image: Forge Viewer Properties]

The result is the same in Navisworks 2020 in using the DGN beta loader (and no properties at all if we use the old one).

Does someone has a process/code to avoid this ratio or has the issue already been raised to Autodesk dev team ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Issue has now been fixed by Forge Viewer updates

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the property display units are determined while translating to SVF by Forge Model Derivative API currently, and `applyScaling` option won't override property display units.

For supporting this, we have a wishlist item `LMV-5097`. Please remember this wishlist item id for future reference, and we will an announcement on our official blog once it is released in the future. So, please stay tuned to our blog. Thanks!